# easy update web application multiple server

Tags: php, capistrano

how to easily update php web application to multiple server ? i read about capistrano, can it be use for PHP ?

Please Help
Regards,
REV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano has support for deployment to multiple environments (development, test, production, etc) and multiple hosts/roles.  Capistrano supports any sort of project that needs to be rolled out to servers, including PHP.

Take a look at [Automated Deployment with Capistrano](http://www.jonmaddox.com/2006/08/16/automated-php-deployment-with-capistrano/)  for a good write-up on the subject.